# How to count the number of occurrences of pixel intensities in an image without using for loop?

Tags: matlab, histogram

I am to writing a script for histogram equalisation and I need to work on each RGB plane separately. In the first step I count the number of occurrences of each intensity value in the range 0-255. As far as I know, using `for` loops makes MATLAB code super slow. This is what I came up with :

```
org_image = imread('image.jpg')
tot_pixel = size(org_image,1) * size(org_image,2)
R = org_image(:,:,1);
G = org_image(:,:,2);
B = org_image(:,:,3);
[R_val_ocurr,R_unique_val] = histcounts(R);
[G_val_ocurr,G_unique_val] = histcounts(G);
[B_val_ocurr,B_unique_val] = histcounts(B);
```

Now to have an array of size 256,with each index holding number of pixels corresponding to it what should my next step be? I'm trying to write down my logic :

```
for i = 0 to 255 
    if i is in R_unique_val
        hist[i] = R_val_ocurr[i]
    else
        hist[i] = 0
```

How to correctly and efficiently write this in MATLAB?

Comment: Have you looked at this function? https://it.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html#buo3qek-4

Comment: *As far as I know, using for loops makes MATLAB code super slow.* That used to be true, long ago. In later years, especially since the new engine in 2016b, loops are hardly slower than non-optimised vectorised statements. Profile your code, and try to optimise it, but do not throw out `for` loops prematurely

Comment: @AndreaBellizzi I am looking into it now, I'll try using it. If you could clarify, in `[counts,binLocations]` will _counts_ be of length 256 even if some pixel intensities are missing? and will binLocations contain bins numbered 0 - 255?

Comment: @momo according to the doc, counts and binLocations are same length and the length is determined by the image type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you have separete the channel you can use **imhist** to get the histogram of each channel:

```
[NumberOfPixelR, intensity] = imhist(R);
[NumberOfPixelG, intensity] = imhist(G);
[NumberOfPixelB, intensity] = imhist(B);
```

Comment: Now if I wanted to divide each element in NumberOfPixelR to get the probability of occurrence, will something like this work : `[R_prob,R_intensities] = [NumberOfPixelR/tot_pixel,intensity];` ?

Comment: in other words, are we supposed to access the elements as a pair?

Comment: yes you can get another array, called R_prob of 256 elements, dividing each element by the tot_pixel but the right syntax is : NewArray = Array/tot_pixel and in this case is: R_prob = NumberOfPixelR/255. P.s matlab is a vectorized programming language that means if you have an array and you have to do an operation on each element, certainly you could do that with a one instruction, whitout access element by element